# Github is not sorting the folders even if they are numeroted

Tags: github

I'm facing a weird issue with GitHub, even if I have numeroted my sub-folders, "1.Folder1, 2.Folder2 etc ...".

They are displayed randomly.

I link you a screenshoot for this.

[image]

You can also see it live here : https://github.com/Ziratsu/Code-source-projets-JS/tree/master/ProjetsTermin%C3%A9s

I made researchs and haven't foud anything about it.

Thank's for the help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not sorted "randomly", but are treated as strings rather than numbers, which doesn't work well for numbered folders.

Left-padding the folder names with 0 should solve this, for instance:

```
001. Quizz
002. AppMeteo
003. Pokedex
004. Cookies
```

Comment: All right they are treated as strings, makes sense now, thank you !